# What could be the best columns for creaing index?

Tags: oracle, indexing, query-optimization

Which columns in this query could possibly optimize the processing?

```
select vintage, wine_no, wname, pctalc, grade, price, wine.vid,
vname, wine.cid, cname
from vineyard, class, wine
where wine.vid = vineyard.vid
and wine.cid = class.cid
and wine.cid = 'SHIRAZ' and grade = 'A' ;
```

Are there any considerations for creating indexes on such tables including joins? If I create an index on vid (foreign key for wine table), would it optimize performance? For wine.vid = vineyard.vid, the query is performing a full table access which is adding a high cost to it? 
Could someone please suggest me some options?

Comment: Your assumption makes sense (creating indexes on `vid` and `cid`). Why don't you try and see for yourself ?

Comment: Well I tried but still it is accessing full table for last predicate which is wine.cid = 'Shiraz' and grade = 'A'

Comment: if you index `cid` the only "problematic" field is grade. But having the joined results filtered by `Shiraz` will reduce the amount of comparisons for `grade` as well. So it shouldn't be a full table scan unless all the wines have `cid = 'Shiraz'`

Comment: I tried with cid but nothing changed.

Comment: The run [`EXPLAIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10752/ex_plan.htm) to see where is your bottleneck!

Comment: SQL tuning is all about the details, of which you have provided very few.  Table structure matters.  You have included CLASS table in query bit it's not obvious why: does it provide GRADE or CNAME?  Use aliases to give us information.  Metrics matter: data volumes, data skew.  How many rows in each table?  How many rows in each table in result set?

Comment: Also, bear in my that FULL TABLE SCAN is not a bad thing in itself.  If the table is small (few rows, compact projection) a FTS and in-memory filtering is likely to be way more efficient than indexed look ups, especially if multiple rows are required.  This is why you need to understand your data.

Comment: wine table has 1500 records, vineyard had 160 all other tables have less than 20 records. If I create index on cid it's selectivity upon calculation is 0.1 same is the case with vid and grade. Statistics show that last line of query has cost 34.

Comment: Cost of accessing wine.cid = 'Shiraz' and grade = 'A' is 34. I tried creating an index on cid and grade with all possible combinations but still I get same results.